# Equivalent of 'in' for comparing two Numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

In pure, unvectorised, Python I can use,

```
>>> a = 9
>>> b = [5, 7, 12]
>>> a in b
False
```

I would like to do something similar for arrays in Numpy i.e.

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
>>> b = np.array([5, 7, 12])
>>> a in b
np.array([False, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, False])
```

... although this does not work.

Is there a function or method that achieves this? If not what is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for [in1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
>>> b = np.array([5, 7, 12])
>>> np.in1d( a, b)
array([False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing two very different things. With the pure Python lists, you have an int and a list. With numpy, you have two numpy arrays. If you change a to an int, then it works as expected in numpy.

```
>>> a = 9
>>> b = np.array([5, 7, 12])
>>> a in b
False
```

Also note that what you show with two lists is quite an intuitive result. The returned array is showing you, for each value in array a, is it in b? 5 and 7 are, the others are not. Hence the given result.

Comment: Yes, the two list case is intuitive, however this is _not_ how Numpy behaves (although I would like it to!) - I have edited to question to make this more clear ...

Comment: Okay, I see that the code you provided does not work. Misread. Although granted, `a in b` works the same for numpy as it does for Python lists.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to implement some sort of string searching algorithms if you are going to test whether one sequence contains another sequence.
[Reference from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm)